# multiple data structures at the same time in Java

Tags: java, data-structures, big-o

I am implementing something called 'Submission History' using Java and there are some following methods:

// Find the highest grade of any submission for a given student

```
public Integer getBestGrade ( String unikey );
```

// The most recent submission for a given student

```
public Submission getSubmissionFinal ( String unikey );
```

// The most recent submission for a given student , prior to a given time

```
public Submission getSubmissionBefore ( String unikey , Date deadline );
```

// Add a new submission ( can assume submissions from one student have different times )

```
public Submission add ( String unikey , Date timestamp , Integer grade );
```

// Remove a submission ( can assume submissions from one student have different times )

```
public void remove ( Submission submission );
```

// Get all the students who have the highest grade

```
public List < String > listTopStudents ();
```

// Get all the students whose most recent submission has lower grade than their best submission

```
public List < String > listRegressions ();
```

However, the main problem that I need to concern about is the time complexity. Each methods need to be ideally in better than O(n) (Except for the last two methods). For example, when using doubly linked list, it takes only O(1) for insertion and deletion, however, it takes O(n) for searching. On the other hand, when using B-tree, it takes O(log n) for searching. So, what I want to ask is, is it possible to use multiple data structures (maximum 3) at the same time? Also, what data structure would be appropriate for each of the methods?(I am thinking of the treeMap...)Thanks!

Comment: So what does your SubmissionHistory class look like so far? And Submission?

Comment: I haven`t started writing down the code since I haven`t  decided which data structure would be appropriate to use of each methods...

Comment: How many students are you expecting to be in your data set? How many submissions for a student?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you to use `HashMap<String, TreeMap<Date, Submission>>` as your data structure.

Then you can:

1. `getBestGrade`: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find best submission in O(N) (You can improve it by caching best score).
2. `getSubmissionFinal`: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find last in O(1)
3. `getSubmissionBefore`: find all submission for student in O(1) and then find result in O(1)
4. `add`: find or add submissions for student in O(1) and then add submission in O(log(N)) (if you implement caching you should update cache here)
5. `remove` find or add submissions for student in O(1) and then remove submission in O(log(N)) (if you implement caching you should update cache here)
6. `listTopStudents` here you need to traverse all submission (if you did not implement caching in `getBestGrade`) which is O(N)
7. `listRegressions` Iterate thru student and check condition will give you O(N) total (again caching will help you here)

Comment: thank you so much talex!! Can you also tell me how to initialize it in the constructor?

Comment: Usually you do it with `new` keyword.